# Does Bean validation works on semantics or syntax.?

Tags: jax-rs, cxf, bean-validation

While reading bean validation specification, I got confused that whether it works on semantics or syntax. 
My view is, it works on semantics through its Constraint Validations.
Please correct me or confirm me on my understanding.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by semantics and syntax and how it relates in the context of bean validation.

Comment: I have a jax rs request which I want to validate, For that I have used bean validation, but my architect says use bean validation for syntax checking and write your own methods for semantics check. Semantics check means the check for allowed data values. and Sytanx check means the check for allowed data types and malformed request.